# Pygame: pygame.error: Unable to open file .ogg

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.5, ogg

OS X ver. `10.11.6`;

Python3 ver. `stable 3.5.2 (bottled), devel 3.6.0rc1, HEAD`(through **Homebrew**);

Pygame ver. `homebrew/python/pygame: stable 1.9.2a0, HEAD`(Both **pip3** and **Homebrew** will got the same error I will state below);

Xcode ver.`Xcode 8.2` `Build version 8C38`.

On **Terminal** I run:

`python3 BattleCity.py`

,which(***BattleCity.py***) is a game-source-code, and **pygame** module is imported in it.

The following is the result from **Terminal**: (For readability I've rearranged the indentation and add/remove some non-visible characters)

```
2016-12-18 21:26:12.739 Python[1600:53113] 21:26:12.739
WARNING:140:
This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component
Manager for hosting Audio Units.

Support for this will be removed in a future release.

Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units.

Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BattleCity.py", line 2074, in <module>
    game = Game()
  File "BattleCity.py", line 1266, in __init__
    sounds["start"] = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/gamestart.ogg")
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'sounds/gamestart.ogg'
```

I have searched through some related questions but their solutions don't work.

In the file I have used `pygame.init()`, but still the same error so I wonder whether or not the two errors above are related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [a post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/4267j7/cant_open_sound_files_using_pygame_on_a_mac/) I found the solution just perfectly works for playing .ogg music-file.

If you're using Homebrew, type the following on Terminal:
(before I run the following code, I check whether I have installed any one below by `brew list`)

```
brew install libogg
brew install libvorbis
brew install sdl_mixer --with-libvorbis
```

If you have installed sol_mixer, and your program still don't work(Yes, it also didn't for me),

Try:

```
brew reinstall sdl_mixer --with-libvorbis
```